# Links on BxSlider Firefox not working

Tags: jquery, carousel, bxslider

On Chrome everything is OK but can't click on links over the images on Firefox.

Exemple : https://kech24.me

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: I just used Firefox and Chrome and bx works on your site.

Comment: Try to click over the images, there is a link but it's not working

Comment: The images in bx are links that are functional in both browsers. Click an image and you are jumped to another page.

Comment: Sorry, it seems it's related to Firefox on Mac

Comment: My version is FF 59.0 (64 bits)

Comment: Mac...ugh. I gotta check my site with my Mac, I'll report back when I find a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if (slider.viewport.get(0).setPointerCapture) {
```

to

```
if (slider.viewport.get(0).setPointerCapture && orig.pointerId) {
```

On line 1109

Fiefox return orig.pointerId = 0 and slider.viewport.get(0).setPointerCapture(slider.pointerId) 
disabled event

Comment: This will  make swiping issue on mobile.